# How to prove not surjective when function is of several variable

Tags: linear-algebra, functions

This is my question:

> Let $A=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2}| x+y\neq -1\}$ and $f: A\to \mathbb{R^2}$ such that, 
>   $$f(x,y) =\left(\frac{y}{1+x+y}, \frac{x}{1+x+y}\right) \ \ \  \text{for every }(x,y) \in A.$$
>   Which of the following **is/are** true?
>   a) $f$ is injective, 
>   b) $f(A)= \mathbb{R^2}$

**My attempt**: taking $f(x,y) = (a,b)$ then we get,

$$\begin{cases} -ax+(1-a)y= a& \\ (1-b)x - by = b \end{cases}$$

After solving above system we get that, determinant of coefficient matrix is non-zero and hence system has unique solution for every $(a,b)$ and hence $f$ is injective. Is am I right? but I can't able to prove/discard $f$ is surjective or not? Please help me.

Comment: "determinant of coefficient matrix is non-zero" – Check that again. What if $a+b=1$?

Comment: The determinant is (ab - (1-a)(1-b))= -1 + a + b which is nonzero whenever a+b $\neq$ 1. When we have a+b=1, what happens when you try to solve that equation? If and only if you can solve it for all such a, b, you have proved surjectivity  because all (a,b) in the plane are image points.

Comment: @marcus sir, martin sir, $a= \frac{y}{1+x+y}$ and $b= \frac{x}{1+x+y}$ (by definition of $f$)so that $a+b=\frac {x+y}{1+x+y}$ so that $a+b≠1$ ? Didn't get it please help me

Comment: I explicitly computed the determinant of your coefficient matrix (i.e. the matrix in the matrix equation Ax=b)

Comment: @marcus sir, but determinant is non zero if $a+b≠1$ but this is indeed true!  So what we get ?

Comment: Take a+b=1. Now solve your system of equations by simply adding them together. You will now have $0+0=a+b=1$. But this is nonsense. (Check for yourself why we get zeroes, using (a+b)=1) Thus for a+b=1, there is no value of (x, y) that gets us (a, b). We fail to have surjectivity.

Answer (score 2):

Hint for surjectivity:  try to solve $\,f(x,y)=(0,1)\,$ for $\,x,y\,$.

Comment: sir, yes there does not exists $(x,y)$ in $A$ such that $ f(x,y)= (0,1)$. So that $f$ is not surjective, But how can we predict $(0,1)$? What if we didn't able to find pair $(0,1)$? Then how we prove surjectivitity?

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi I'd call that "*by inspection*", once you work out a few cases like this, it tends to jump to the eye.

Comment: Sir, isn't there is general method? rather than, by finiding such pairs.

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi See how the above ties up with the $\,a+b=1\,$ case mentioned in the comments. Keep in mind that *one* counterexample is enough to disprove any given statement.

Comment: Just saying, proofs by inspection are not the best pedagogical tool; they aren't motivated (from the perspective of the student) and they don't carry lessons in problem solving with them. Things should be motivated to a decent extent—constructions that are pulled from thin air and that happen to work are technically satisfactory but not for the purpose of education.

Comment: @MarcusAurelius That's a good point in general, but it's not exactly pulled out of "*thin air*" here in particular. The given expressions invite the observation that $f_x+f_y = \frac{x+y}{x+y+1}$ cannot be $1$, so $f(x,y)=(0,1)$ would be a natural thing to check for early on. Just like noticing "*by inspection*" that a polynomial whose coefficients add up to $0$ must have $1$ as a root, for example.

Comment: Yeah, I see your point. It would definitely help if you had explicitly stated that as your motivation: I'm glad you did just now (it was instructive for me too, because I saw the problem as a row-reduction bash and not this elegant little move).

Comment: @MarcusAurelius I always try to answer any followup questions, even though I don't necessarily give it all away in the  "*hints*" I post.